# How can I force a Google Spreadsheets to have column in one tab have the same width as the same column in a different tab?

Tags: google-sheets

Is there any way to force a Google Spreadsheets to have column `i` in tab `j` of same width as column `i` in tab `k`?

In other words, can I configure Google Spreadsheets so that a column width change is always applied to all sheets in a Google Spreadsheets document?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with an Apps Script. To use, enter it in (Tools > Script editor), save, and add a trigger via (Resources > This project's triggers) with parameters "from spreadsheet" and "on change".

The change of column width is an [event](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) of type "OTHER". It doesn't seem possible to detect which column was changed; only what sheet (tab) it came from. So I record the width of all columns in that sheet, and set their counterparts accordingly.

An assumption made here is that the column whose length was modified is within the [data range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getDataRange()) of the sheet: that is, either it contains some data, or some column to the right of it does.

```
function syncWidths(e) {
  if (e.changeType === 'OTHER') {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); 
    var widths = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < activeSheet.getLastColumn(); i++) {
      widths.push(activeSheet.getColumnWidth(i));
    }
    var sheets = ss.getSheets();
    for (var j = 0; j < sheets.length; j++) {
      if (sheets[j] == activeSheet) {
        continue;
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < widths.length; i++) {
        sheets[j].setColumnWidth(i + 1, widths[i]);
      }
    }
  }  
}
```